# How to display content for a ruby game?

Tags: ruby

I am wanting to do a game in Ruby, but I came across a problem. I am intermediate level in Ruby. I only know of running Ruby through the command line but to make the game I am thinking of similar to Dwarf Fortress would require something more.

I need to be able to use arrow keys and enter to select things. I also need 2 frames displaying, one for the map and one for in-game information.

How do I go about doing this? Would I need to use a GUI or something to that effect. If it can't be a desktop app, that's fine. I have a vague idea of how I could do it in the browser.

Comment: This is basically a question that can be answered by googling. I see your brand spanking new, but please read the FAQ on what types of questions to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the gosu gem which gives you a 2d game engine from www.libgosu.org

```
gem install gosu
# complete with examples, precompiled for Windows & OS X
gem install texplay
# pixel-based drawing on Gosu images, by banister
gem install chingu
# a library that adds more game logic, by ippa
gem install ruby-opengl
# the standard Ruby OpenGL gem works fine with Gosu to add 3D effects
# (See the included example, or this fine bundle of tutorials by tjbladez. Also note this thread if you have problems installing on Windows)
gem install chipmunk
# a popular physics library with an integration example in the wiki
gem install rmagick
# can be used as a more powerful but harder-to-distribute alternative to TexPlay, example included in Gosu
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ruby-gl

http://ruby-opengl.rubyforge.org/